# SQL SELECT WHERE column has all delimited strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with columns like this:

`Table: teeburu
Columns:
- aidi int identity
- bariu varchar(8000)`

I want to have a stored procedure which its input is a string, for example: 
`abc qwe ax xyza`
The length and how many spaces are free for the user to input.

And what it does is to select all rows which the column `bariu` contains **all** of these: `abc`, `qwe`, `ax`, and `xyza`

Here is what I tried:

I create split function (copied from [this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e676a8e3-ae55-44b6-b36c-fdcd1ef3c70b/sql-to-split-the-string-based-on-the-space-example-split-the-firstname-alone-from-the-complete?forum=transactsql))

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[Split](@String varchar(8000), @Delimiter char(1))
returns @temptable
TABLE (nameIndex int identity(1,1),items varchar(8000))
as
begin
    declare @idx int
    declare
    @slice varchar(8000)

    select @idx = 1
    if len(@String)<1 or @String
    is null return

    while @idx!= 0
    begin
    set @idx =
    charindex(@Delimiter,@String)
    if @idx!=0
    set @slice = left(@String,@idx
    - 1)
    else
    set @slice = @String

    if(len(@slice)>0)
    insert
    into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)

    set @String =
    right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)
    if len(@String) = 0 break
    end

return
end
```

With it, I managed to write something to select all rows which the column `bariu` contains **at least one** of these: `abc`, `qwe`, `ax`, and `xyza`

```
with list as(
    select * from dbo.split(@Param,' ')
)
SELECT aidi, bariu FROM teeburu
    INNER JOIN list
    ON bariu like '%'+ list.items+ '%'
    GROUP BY aidi, bariu
```

But I can't figure out how to do **all** instead of **at least one of**. My question is how to do it?

I am using MS SQL SERVER

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only add `HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list)`

```
with list as(
    select * from dbo.split('abc qwe ax xyza',' ')
)
SELECT aidi, bariu  FROM teeburu
    INNER JOIN list
    ON bariu like '%'+ list.items+ '%'    
    GROUP BY aidi, bariu
    HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will modify the split function to fetch count of parameter also.

Doing this won't increase won't increase my task nor any perfromance imptact.

```
TABLE (nameIndex int identity(1,1),items varchar(8000),ParamCount int)
```

Then you are already looping so take one variable and increase its value on each loop
insert value of variable here,

```
insert into @temptable(Items,ParamCount) values(@slice,@Newvar)
```

Advantage : you will escape from one count(*) statement.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM list
```

So final query,

```
 SELECT aidi
    ,bariu
FROM teeburu
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT Items
        ,paramcount
    FROM dbo.split('abc qwe ax xyza', ' ')
    ) list
WHERE bariu LIKE '%' + list.items + '%'
GROUP BY aidi
    ,bariu
HAVING COUNT(*) = list.paramcount
```

Also it depend upon your real query and table.May be you should 
use row_number instead of group by so many column